# Buttons dont add to Jframe

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, grid-layout

I can't create a field with this code.

I want to load a file and the field should add arrays for the specific size. The problem is that the buttons are not shown in the frame. 
Does anyone have an idea why they are not in the `gridLayout`? I already tested some options but its still not working.

```
package Gui;

import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Feld extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //Deklaration von Variablen 

    JMenuBar jMenuBar;
    JMenu datei, filter, hilfe;

    JMenuItem neu;
    JMenuItem oeffnen;
    JMenuItem speichern;
    JMenuItem beenden;
    int hoehe = 100;
    int breite = 100;
    JMenuItem invertieren;
    JMenuItem Graustufen;
    JMenuItem HorizontalSpiegeln;
    JMenuItem VertikalSpiegeln;

    JMenuItem ueberPixelart;


    private GridLayout gridLayout;

    //erstellen eines Fensters und einer Menüleiste

    public void felderstellen() {

        jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Zuordnen meiner Variablen zum Fenster

        datei = new JMenu("Datei");
        filter = new JMenu("Filter");
        hilfe = new JMenu("Hilfe");


        neu = new JMenuItem("neu");
        oeffnen = new JMenuItem("öffnen");
        beenden = new JMenuItem("beenden");
        speichern = new JMenuItem("Hilfe");

        invertieren = new JMenuItem("invertieren");
        Graustufen = new JMenuItem("Graustufen");
        HorizontalSpiegeln = new JMenuItem("Horizontal spiegeln");
        VertikalSpiegeln = new JMenuItem("Vertikal spiegeln");

        ueberPixelart = new JMenuItem("über Pixel Art");


        //Hinzufügen der Menüpunkte zu den Oberpunkten

        datei.add(oeffnen);
        datei.add(neu);
        datei.add(speichern);
        datei.add(beenden);

        filter.add(invertieren);
        filter.add(Graustufen);
        filter.add(HorizontalSpiegeln);
        filter.add(VertikalSpiegeln);

        hilfe.add(ueberPixelart);

        oeffnen.addActionListener(this);

        jMenuBar.add(datei);
        jMenuBar.add(filter);
        jMenuBar.add(hilfe);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1000, 2000);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == oeffnen) {
            dateieinladen();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == beenden) {
            schließen();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == hilfe) {
            hilfe();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void schließen() {
    }

    private void hilfe() {
    }

    private void dateieinladen() {

        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setDirectory("C:\\");
        fd.setFile("*.txt");
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String filename = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();


        if (filename == null)
            System.out.println("You cancelled the choice");
        else
            System.out.println("You chose " + filename);


        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            String line;
            reader.readLine();
            String hoeheBreite = reader.readLine();
            int länge = hoeheBreite.split(" ").length;
            String[] laenge = hoeheBreite.split(" ");

            this.hoehe = Integer.parseInt(laenge[0]);
            this.breite = Integer.parseInt(laenge[1]);

            System.out.println(hoehe);
            System.out.println(breite);


            erstelleFeld(hoehe, breite);


            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void erstelleFeld(int hoehe, int breite) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(hoehe, breite));

        JLabel[] aHoehe = new JLabel[hoehe];
        JLabel[] aBreite = new JLabel[breite];
        JButton[][] buttons = new javax.swing.JButton[hoehe][breite];

        System.out.print(hoehe);
        System.out.print(breite);
        for (int i = 0; i < hoehe; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < breite; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    aBreite[j] = new JLabel("");
                    add(aBreite[j]);
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    aHoehe[i] = new JLabel("");
                    add(aHoehe[i]);
                }
                add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcelGe You cannot expect that anyone will try to figure out what is wrong with your 200 lines of poorly formatted code. Please read how to create a [mcve] before posting. And in general this site uses English, so if you're looking for help, it is a good idea to add least translate the comments. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it you never instantiate the `JButton`s like this:

```
   for(int y = 0; y < hoehe; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < breite; x++){
            buttons[y][x] = new JButton();
        }
    }
```

After doing that you can add the `JButton`s to your `JFrame`

> As mentioned in a comment to your question, it might be a good idea to translate the german comments, as not everybody will understand you.